# Redux Toolkit: How to update state inside reducer after fetching data from the server?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a couple of reducer functions inside my `checkoutSlice.js` file.
Specifically inside **`fetchCheckout`** function I'm trying to fetch data  (it's successfully fetching)
and store it in the state as `checkout`.
But for some reason it gives me this mistake: **`TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked`** 
on this line: `.catch((err) => console.log(err));`

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import Client from 'shopify-buy';

// Initializing a client to return content in the store's primary language
const client = Client.buildClient({
    storefrontAccessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN,
});

const initialState = {
    checkout: null,
    checkoutID: null,
    isCartOpen: false,
}

const checkoutSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'checkout',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        createCheckout(state, action) {
                state.checkout = client.checkout.create();
            localStorage.setItem('checkout', checkout.id);
            },
        fetchCheckout(state, action) {
            console.log(state)
            console.log(action)
            client.checkout
                .fetch(action.payload)
                .then((checkout) => {
                    console.log(checkout.lineItems)
                    state.checkout =  checkout;
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
    }
})
```

I kinda see the mistake here, I'm probably violating some of these rules:
[image: redux toolkit documentation]

But I don't know how to implement better decisions here.
Previously I was using Context API for state management and it worked well. Now I want to keep the same logic and keep fetching functions and the state at the same globally accessible place.

**Any suggestions, recommendations on how to do it a better way?
Thank you in advance**

Comment: Please give the "Async Logic and Data fetching" chapter of the official Redux Essentials tutorial (which handles RTK) a read: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic